# Guide to install an edX platform

Tags: edx

I want to learn how to install the edX platform in my own server and then create lessons. Is there any book to guide me step by step the installation?

I have found this [guide](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/index.html) from edX but it confuses me..

Answer (score 2):

That is the best guide we have.  If you could let us know where it needs to be clarified, we can make improvements.  Slack or mailing lists are the best place to go: https://open.edx.org/resources/e-mail-lists